# Не ищет по ключам в массиве

Tags: массивы, php

Есть код

```
foreach ($files_in_dir as $num_file => $name_file) {
    $file = file($name_file);
    $found = false;
    foreach ($file as $line_num => $line_text) {
        $i = 0;
        $keyword = array('а');
        foreach ($keyword as $num => $search) {
            $i++;
            if (strpos($line_text, $search) !== false) {
                $found = true;
                $num_line[] = $line_num + 1;
                $text_num_line[] = htmlspecialchars(trim($line_text), ENT_QUOTES);
            }
        }
    }
    if ($found == true) {
        echo '<div class="copyright"><b> /' . $name_file . '</b>:</div>';
        $count = count($num_line);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $count - 1; $i++) {
            echo '<div class="content"><b>Строка ' . $num_line[$i] . ':</b> '
                                                   . $text_num_line[$i] . '</div>';
        }
        $num_line = '';
    }
}
```

в нем сейчас есть массив

```
$keyword = array('а');
```

мне нужно чтобы он искал по нескольким ключам

```
$keyword = array('а', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

но когда делаю так как выше, он ищет только те строки в которых присутствуют все 4 ключа, а не в тех где присутствует один из ключей.

как можно это исправить?

Comment: @Eugene Smiths, пожалуйста, уделяйте больше внимания форматированию кода. От такого

    if (strpos($line_text, $search) !== false) {$found=true;  $num_line[]=$line_num+1; $text_num_line[]=htmlspecialchars(trim($line_text), ENT_QUOTES);}

хочется плакать и пропадает всякая мотивация

Answer (score 1):

Всё прекрасно работает:

```
$keys = array('a','b');

print find_keys( 'a c', $keys )."\n";
print find_keys( 'a b', $keys )."\n";
print find_keys( 'b c', $keys )."\n";
print find_keys( 'c d', $keys )."\n";

function find_keys( $string, $keys )
{
    $found = 0;
    foreach ($keys as $key)
    {
        if( strpos($string, $key) !== false )
        {
            $found++;
        }
    }
    return $found;
}
```

Вывод:

```
1
2
1
0
```

Если не нужно считать количество ключей:

```
foreach ($keys as $key)
{
    if( strpos($string, $key) !== false )
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: таким макаром, он только ключи выводит, а не строку целиком

Comment: Как вам выводить строку - решайте самостоятельно. Я просто продемонстрировал, что поиск по ключам работает как нужно, а не "**ищет только те строки в которых присутствуют все 4 ключа**".

Comment: я же в топике написал, если в массиве несколько ключей, то он ищет строку в которой "имеются все ключи"

Comment: То есть вы видите код, который находит **любое** вхождение, и при этом продолжаете утверждать, что он находит **только все**?